# Book where phantom limbs of amputees are used in a heist

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this book in the early 2000s when it was - as far as I remember - still quite new. It was some kind of science fiction about people with missing limbs that were recruited for some kind of heist. They were trained to use their "phantom limbs" to telekinetically operate some kind of vault.

If I recall correctly, there was also some nanotechnology involved that altered the blood.

Answer (score -1):

Could it be Larry Nivens's "Flatlander"? First published in 1976, this is a 1995 collection updated with more stories. The main character is Gil Hamilton, a detective in a future society where people mine asteroids. His right arm was cut off in an accident, and he discovered his phantom limb could actually move small objects via telekinesis, even reaching through walls and video screens

Comment: This doesn't sound like a very good match. Was there a heist in this book?